# This function gives me "Program run out of memory"?

Tags: scheme, racket

I wrote a function called `(element-at  x  k)` that has two parameters: a list `x` and a number `k`. It returns the K'th element of the list.

For example, the expression `(element-at '(a b c d) 3)` returns `c`.
then a function called `(remove-at  x  y)` that has two parameters: a list `x` and a number `k`. It removes the K'th element from the list. For example, the expression `(remove-at '(a b c d) 3)` returns `(a b d)`.

In the definition of `(remove-at  x  y)` I used the function `(element-at  x  k)` but the function `(remove-at  x  y)` won't work and Dr.racket gives me "Program run out of memory", Can any one knows why and fix it as soon as possible?

```
(define (element-at lis k) (if (null? lis) (if (> k 0) #f '()) (let ((head (car lis)) (tail (cdr lis))) (if (< k 2) head (element-at tail (- k 1))))))

(define (remove-at x y) (let ((first (element-at x y)) (tail x)) (if (equal? (car x) first) (append (remove-at x y) (cdr tail)) (cdr tail))))
```

Comment: Please [indent](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/proglang/scheme/indentation.html) [things](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-style) [properly](http://dept-info.labri.u-bordeaux.fr/~idurand/enseignement/PFS/Common/Strandh-Tutorial/indentation.html). Also, please learn to use your `ret` key.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, when properly arranged, your code reads

```
(define (element-at lis k)
  (if (null? lis)
      (if (> k 0) #f '())
      (let ((head (car lis))
            (tail (cdr lis)))
        (if (< k 2)
            head
            (element-at tail (- k 1))))))

(define (remove-at x y)
  (let ((first (element-at x y))
        (tail x))
    (if (equal? (car x) first)
        (append (remove-at x y) (cdr tail))
        (cdr tail))))
```

Why do you use `element-at` to assign `first` in `remove-at`? Why do you assign `tail` to the complete list that was passed in? As written, even if it wasn't giving you a memory error, think about what `(remove-at '(a b c d e f c d) 7)` would return, given how you decide which element to remove.

As mentioned, since you're doing `(append (remove-at x y) (cdr tail))`, your list and number never actually get smaller. You've written a recursion that doesn't approach a result. As a consequence, `remove-at` is going to spin forever, `append`ing `x` to its own `cdr` (unless `(car x)` happens to be initially `equal?` to `(element-at x y)`).

I assume this is a homework assignment, so I've only pointed out your mistakes and leave fixing them as an exercise. If that's not the case, let me know so we can go over a working version.

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
(define (element-at lis k) 
   ( if(null? lis)
       (if(> k 0) #f '()) 
       ( let( (head (car lis))(tail (cdr lis)) ) 
       (if(< k 2) head (element-at tail (- k 1 )))) ) )

(define (remove-at x y)
   (let ((first (element-at x y))
        (tail x))
    (if (equal? (car x) first)
        (cdr tail)
        (cons (car x) (remove-at (cdr tail) (- y 1))))))
```

(remove-at (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 3) returns '(a b d).  But may i just say that this is probably a very bad implementation of such a simple requirement. Did you deliberately write it as such so as to get a deeper understanding of if condition?. Here is a simplified code without using auxiliary functions. Caveat:- In the above function if you enter (remove-at (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 5), it gives error and not "false" as expected. Here is a simpler implementation:

```
(define (remove-at2 x y)
  (local ((define (remove x y ans-lst)
            (cond ((null? x)
                  (if (> y 0) #f
                      ans-lst))
                  ((= y 1) (append ans-lst (cdr x)))
                  (else
                    (remove (cdr x) (- y 1) (append ans-lst (list (car x))))))))
    (remove x y '())))
```

(remove-at2 (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 5) retruns false.
(remove-at2 (list 'a 'b 'c 'd) 3) returns '(a b d)